# Fopen didn't open the file, but file exist

Tags: c++, fopen

I write

```
FILE * new_file = fopen("Penguins.jpg","rb");
```

I fully confident that file exist and it is in right directory. I also tried a lot of various modes like  `"rb+"` `"r"`. I also chanded path like `fopen("C:\Penguins.jpg","rb");` Compilator always says :

[image]

Besides, openCV open the file. But i need in `FILE*`. What wrong?

Comment: printf((new_file!=NULL)?"File was opened!\n":"File open failed!\n");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of fopen from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

The file opens successfully is the function returns a non-null pointer:

> If the file is successfully opened, the function returns a pointer to a FILE object that can be used to identify the stream on future operations.
>   Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.

So because your variable `new_file` (**not** `new_file->_ptr`) is valid, the file should be opened.

Comment: This answer does not contradict what I wrote in my own answer, but it does address the problem more accurately (by explaining that in fact no such problem exists). So I would mark this one as the accepted one.

Comment: you right, yes) 
null-pointers in debug just confused me. And next fails in other library with the file too. Thank a lot

Answer (score 3):

In order to denote a special character within a string, it must be preceded with a backslash.

Since the backslash itself is also a special character, it must be preceded with yet another backslash.

**So change this:**

```
fopen("C:\Penguins.jpg","rb");
```

**To this:**

```
fopen("C:\\Penguins.jpg","rb");
```

Please note that you need to apply this **only** for strings that are part of the code, i.e., strings that are "treated" by the compiler, not by the preprocessor (such as names of included header files, for example).